# Microsoft SQL Server trigger updating a table row with change from another table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tables `zipTbl` and `locationTBl` with four common columns

```
zipCode
City
stateCode
salesTaxRate
```

If the `zipCode` changes in the `locationTbl` say from '91311' to '10172' I want the `city`, `stateCode`, `salesTaxRate` in the `locationTBL` to be updated with the same values in the `zipTbl` where the `zipCode` is the new value '10172'

`zipCode` is the primary key for the `zipTbl` and a foreign key in the `locationTbl`.

I use the following to create a trigger but it only updates from the first row in the `zipTBL` not the row with the new `zipCode`

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_city_state on dbo.locationTbl
AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN
     UPDATE locationTbl
     SET locationTbl.city = zipTbl.city,
         LocationTbl.stateCode = zipTbl.stateCode,
         locationTbl.salesTaxRate = zipTbl.salesTaxRate 
     FROM zipTbl
END
```

I have tried several combinations of adding "where locationTbl.zipCode = zipTbl.zipcode," but I keep getting syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

I think it's like this:

```
UPDATE locationTbl
SET locationTbl.city=zipTbl.city,
    LocationTbl.stateCode=zipTbl.stateCode,
    locationTbl.salesTaxRate=zipTbl.salesTaxRate
FROM locationTbl t1
JOIN inserted i
  ON t1.zipCode=i.zipCode
JOIN zipTbl
  ON i.zipCode=zipTbl.zipCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_city_state on dbo.locationTbl AFTER Update 
AS 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE locationTbl 
  SET locationTbl.city = INSERTED.city, 
  LocationTbl.stateCode = INSERTED.stateCode, 
  locationTbl.salesTaxRate = INSERTED.salesTaxRate 
  FROM INSERTED
  WHERE locationTbl.zipCode = INSERTED.zipcode
```

Comment: You need a join between locationTbl and INSERTED. As posted this doesn't work.

Comment: It is the locationTbl where the zipCode is changed and I want to update the city, state, taxrate in the locationTbl from the zipCodeTbl